# jQuery fadeIn/Out Search Field

Tags: jquery, html, css

Fellow Stackers,

I'm looking to have a search button "transform" into a search field.

This is what I've got so far, but the animation is super wonky.

HTML

```
<div id='search'>
    <span id='text'>Search</span><span id='field' style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="firstname"></input></span><a href='#' id='btn_go'>Go</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#search span {
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#search {
    background-color: #09F;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#btn_go  {
    background-color: #06C;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

JS

```
$( "#btn_go" ).click(function() {
  $( "#text" ).fadeToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

      $( "#field" ).fadeToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/75DUC/

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the cross-fade (field overlaps with text) set `#text` to `position: absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/75DUC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning will fix your issue.  You will have to play with the width and height values, but here is a rough approximation of what you are looking for: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsaat14/GDN3D/12/)**

Updated CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#search span {
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#search {
    background-color: #09F;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    width:250px;
    position:relative;
}
#text{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 150px;
}
#field{
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#btn_go  {
    background-color: #06C;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsaat14/GDN3D/27/) to include the expanding search box.  I used CSS transitions and a little extra jQuery to make it work.

**Extra jQuery:**

```
  var search = $('#search')
  var width = search.width();
  if(width == 125){
      search.width('250px');
  }
  else{
      search.width('125px');
  }
```

**Extra CSS:**

```
#search {
    transition: width 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: I was actually wanting the search field to "grow" in, expanding the container from right to left.

Comment: @AaronBenjamin I have edited my answer to include this.